# NodeJS - EJS receive data client side

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have this NodeJS router file, which uses Express and EJS. I'm trying to send data from the server to the client side.

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    let myObj = {
        name: 'Bob',
        age: '31'
    }
    res.render('test', {
        myObj: JSON.stringify(myObj)
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

In my `test.ejs` file, I have the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
        console.log('<%= myObj %>')
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <%= myObj %>
</body>
</html>
```

In the body tags, the object is displayed. But when I try use JS to console log the object, this text is printed out instead:
[text in console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pFN3.png).
What's the issue and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the unescaped tag for this. See tags in the [documentation](https://ejs.co/#docs):

```js
  console.log('<%- myObj %>')
```